# How to serve gatsby development build on local network using https?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I have tried this command:

```
gatsby develop --host $(hostname) --https
```

but get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a custom host, you need to provide the ssl certificate paths. As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/)

> Keep in mind that the automatic certificates issued with the `--https`
>   flag are explicitly issued to `localhost` and will only be accepted
>   there. Using it together with the `--host` option will likely result in
>   browser warnings.

You would need to specify it as follows

```
gatsby develop --host $(hostname) --https --key-file ../relative/path/to/key.key --cert-file ../relative/path/to/cert.crt
```

If you only wish to use `https` on `localhost` you may start the development server using `npm run develop` as usual, and add either the `-S or --https` flag.

```
npm run develop -- --https
```

You may be required to perform an initial setup for which you can refer the [following doc.](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/#setup)

Comment: Ah okay, let me try this.

Comment: Am getting this error when using open ssl. Any idea why? I have reaerched this a bunch but to no avail:   Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt